# XSS prevention in wordpress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, xss

Is it possible to prevent saving  tags in the Wordpress post/page content editor as shown in the image below?

eg. alert(1)

[image]

Comment: Great posting.  One thing that might help get responses is to circle the area of concern on the posted image just to focus peoples attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-xss-vulnerability/ plugin to prevent xss attacks. This worked for me.